# Autohotkey: Show compiled script icon

Tags: scripting, icons, autohotkey

Can anyone explain me, how can I show icon of my script at the custom window?
When I compile my script, I'm using Compile_AHK and choosing my custom icon.
But I can't make it showing in my script's window.
I've tryed to show like an image, like an icon, to pack it like resource, but still no result.
I found [this tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/37699-tutorial-how-to-compile-ahk-files-include-your-own-icons/), but script code of it's about window shows nothing at the icons places.

It would be useful to lear how can i show some icon without using external one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your test.ahk file in e.g. C:\Users\Robert\AHK

Create your test.ico file in the same directory (C:\Users\Robert\AHK)
Open a CMD window from C:\Users\Robert\AHK (Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Right Click)
In CMD run:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler\Ahk2Exe.exe" /in test.ahk /icon test.ico
```

Comment: When I open it on my computer - it shows it's icon, but when I run compiled script on another computer - icon place is empty (It shows text "icon.ico")
Gui, Add, Picture, x12 y12 w64 h64 , icon.ico

What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you have done. As Armin said before, show what you have done, what code you use  and how you compiled.

Comment: There's tray menu calling GUI Window - WINDOW:
Gui, Add, Picture, x12 y12 w64 h64 , icon.ico

I've copliled using Compile AHK, choosing "icon.ico" like main icon and also included it icon in resources. How can I show that icon in my GUI now? Thanks

Comment: The only way I made it showing is:  Gui, Add, Picture, x372 y10 w64 h64 , %A_ScriptFullPath%. Any other ideas?